# Manipulating button via DOM, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to find the index of a clicked button, so that I can manipulate other elements with the same index, but I don't know how!

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="area">
            <h1>JavaScript</h1>
            <button class="knapp">Click!</button>
            <p class="text">Adöfkljg ldjfögj jsdflkgjh kjddflkgjh dfgkjdöjg </p>
            <button class="knapp">Click!!</button>
            <p class="text">dfghödifgjöoeirugeöori dijfoidj oidoi odi!</p>
        </div>
        <script src="visa.js"></script>
    </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
var butt = document.getElementsByClassName("knapp");

window.onload = start();
function start(){
    for (i=0; i<text.length; i++){
        text[i].style.visibility = "hidden";

    };
};

this.onclick = function(){
    var index = butt.indexOf(this);
};
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x9LGG/2/

Comment: According to update you can `show/hide` `p` element :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="area">
    <h1>JavaScript</h1>
    <button class="knapp">Click!</button>
    <p class="text">Adöfkljg ldjfögj jsdflkgjh kjddflkgjh dfgkjdöjg </p>
    <button class="knapp">Click!!</button>
    <p class="text">dfghödifgjöoeirugeöori dijfoidj oidoi odi!</p>
</div>
```

Try this `JavaScript`, you will get index of button when certain button will be clicked:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("knapp");
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

for ( var i = 0; i < button.length; i++ ) (function(j){
    button[j].addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(j); // shows index
    if ( txt[j].style.visibility == "hidden" ) { // show hides p element depend on button index
        txt[j].style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        txt[j].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    },false);
})(i);
```

It will alert `0` when first button is clicked and `1` when second one, so you'll be able to manipulate other elements with it ( and also hides certain `p` element )

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLE5x/3/)</kbd>

**NOTE:** In your script on here `this.onclick...` `this` keyword refers to `window` Object, in this manner you can't achieve your goal

Comment: Thank you so much for (trying) to help me. I can see that it is working but I still don't understand why and how. I have to study som more...

Comment: @Delal It's called immediate functions, maybe this will help you http://www.jspatterns.com/self-executing-functions/  this one too http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to use jquery for this. JQuery has inbuilt methods to get index.

Comment: I have to use JavaScript, it is for a school assignment.

Comment: If you don't see a jQuery tag, don't just tell the OP to use jQuery. Your answer does not even contain code.